# See all cards assigned to a user

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-boards

Is there a way to see all the cards that have been assigned to a user on:

1. a single board?
2. across all the boards?

This would be much like the cards link below my profile box that I can click to see all my cards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to a member's profile (such as https://trello.com/aarond), you will see a "Cards" link just like on your own profile.  This will show all cards that the person is assigned to on any board that you are allowed to see.

On a single board, you can open the right sidebar, open the "Menu", and click "Filter Cards" (or press 'f' on your keyboard).  From there, you can filter the cards on the board by user (or by card title, labels, or due date).

Comment: Another great thing on that profile page is that you can also sort your cards on Due Dates, across all boards.

Comment: The "member profile" trick is very useful; maybe you should add a shortcut somewhere in the app itself so that team managers can discover this feature easily?